# AJAX is reloading page on a SharePoint site (SharePoint 2007 AJAX-enabled)

Tags: ajax, sharepoint

I have an AJAX-enabled SharePoint 2007 site. I have also created a user control that has an interactive ajax form. It obviuosly works like a charm locally, but I am trying to get it working on the SharePoint site. The problem is that once I load up the user control on to an aspx page inside SharePoint, the form (which has ajax), causes the page to reload every time a postback occurs. Can someone help point me in the direction of debugging this? - I really need to eliminate the page refreshes and have the ajax work correctly in SharePoint. I read that the ScriptManager has to be in the SharePoint masterpage, but that did not work either... Page still reloads everytime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross check whether you have installed Ajax extension in the sharepoint server. Make sure whether you have the web.config setup correctly to make ajax work. You can make use of the feature ajax.config available here - http://features.codeplex.com/.

Comment: I have definitely installed the Ajax extensions to the SharePoint server.

Comment: Did you try that feature? Can you create a simple webpart with a single ajax control in it and check it?

Comment: figure out the problem... AJAX wasn't installed properly, you were right.